# Refresh authenticated user without relogin in symfony

Tags: symfony, oauth

My SF2.8 project is an API using oAuth2 coupling with FOSUserBundle.

I created a custom user provider to get another user data from an external API that i put on my FOSUser connected.

Every X seconds, i've implemented a listener which test if a user is connected and need to be refresh from external API like this :

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    // don't do anything if it's not the master request
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        return;
    }

    $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();

    if (!is_null($token) && !is_null($token->getUser())) {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if ($user->needToRefresh($this->ttl)) {
            $refreshedUserData = $this->provider->loadUserFromClient($user->getEmail());

            if ($refreshedUserData) {
                $refreshedUserCompanies = isset($refreshedUserData['usrCompany']) ? $refreshedUserData['usrCompany'] : [];
                $refreshedCompanies = $this->provider->getFormatedUserCompanies($refreshedUserCompanies);

                $user->setCompanies($refreshedCompanies);
                $user->setRefreshedAt(new \DateTime());

                $token->setUser($user);
                return;
            }

            //Forcing disconnect to connected user
            $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
            $this->container->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();

            return new Response(json_encode([
                'data' => '',
                'message' => 'User not found'
            ]), 404, array(
                "Content-Type" => "application/json"
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

But in my next request, my user isn't refreshed. I read on some stack answers that if you want to update your connected user, you need to reinstanciate a Userpasswordtoken and set a new token into security.context.

However if I chose this solution, my oAuth connection is lost and i need to completely re authenticate my user with oAuth and ask a new token.

This is my custom loadUserFromUsername method implemented in my provider :

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $user = $this->manager->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($username);

    if (is_null($user)) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }

    $userData = $this->loadUserFromClient($user->getEmail());

    if ($userData) {
        $userCompanies = isset($userData['usrCompany']) ? $userData['usrCompany'] : [];
        $companies = $this->getFormatedUserCompanies($userCompanies);

        $user->setCompanies($companies);
        $user->setRefreshedAt(new \DateTime());

        return $user;
    }

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
        sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
    );
}
```

**EDIT**: Solved my problem, i forgot to flush the user updated to my entity manager.

But i don't like this solution because of flushing all time in case of refresh. I decided to use session but I've got another problem, my session is null in my listener :

Adding to my loadUserByUsername:

```
$this->session->set('timer_test', new \DateTime());
```

$this->session is used by @session passed on arguments in my service.

Adding to my listener:

```
//Persisting & flush user to DB
$this->manager->persist($user);
$this->manager->flush();

$timer = $this->session->get('timer_test');
```

but $timer is null.

Comment: have you tried to use the rememberMe functionality of symfony?http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html might solve your issue

Comment: I solved my problem, i forgot to flush my user and it's work. But it's maybe better to use session instead of flushing every request ? Because i don't need these infos in database

Comment: A session is preferable as that information should be valid only an certain time and not unlimited. Another User could grab the token you use for authentication and you might have the same issue like dropbox had a couple of years ago with the unencrypted user password/name token that it stored in plane text on the hard drive

Comment: Mmh ok. But i try with session and my session is null when i grab it in my listener. I edit post with my code

Comment: Updated now with my session problem.